# How do I play MechWarrior 2: Mercenaries online on a modern OS?

Tags: networking, backwards-compatibility, mechwarrior-2-mercenaries

Is there a way to play the online multiplayer of *MechWarrior 2: Mercenaries* (1996) on a modern OS?

Comment: Does MechWarrior2 have TCP Connections already? If not, there was a program called Kali back in those days that allowed playing IPX over TCP (or something like that).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about MW2 but MW4 has been re-acquired by the original franchise creator and released for free - you can download it off Battletech.com and connect using MekTek.

Comment: What you'd need is a classic-games-fan-chat/meeting-room/software. If you find something, I'd also like to know :).

Comment: You probably noticed already, but just in case: [Mechwarrior: Living Legends](http://www.mechlivinglegends.net/) is already quite good even though it's technically still beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is the [MechWarrior 2: Resource Forum](http://www.mech2.org/forum/index.php).  They even have a server for multiplayer.

For those of you playing at home it does indeed use IPX.

---

Bonus: [MechWarrior 3](http://www.mechwarrior3.org/)